# Django: Annotate Multiple Queries

Tags: python, django

Here's my code,

```
data1 = Data.objects.filter(...).annotate(Max('receiver')).order_by('-receiver__max')

data2 = Data.objects.filter(...).annotate(Max('sender')).order_by('-sender__max')
```

How can I combine these 2 queries in just one single Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine it quite nicely, and if you're only interested in the max values then there's no need to also `order_by`. You should just be able to do;

```
data = Data.objects.filter(...).annotate(Max('receiver'), Max('sender'))
```

Which should return something like;

```
{'receiver__max': 10, 'sender__max': 12}
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine. Thank You Sir!